# Can we write $P(A > B)$ in terms of their quantile functions?

Tags: probability, quantiles

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two independent, continuous random variables with bounded supports $[min, max]$ and densities $f_A(a), f_B(b)$ and CDFs $F_A(a), F_B(b)$. Can we write $P(A > B)$ in terms of their quantile functions? Right now, I know

\begin{align}
   P(A > B) &= P(A > B | B = b)f_B(b) \text{ by conditional probability } \\\\
            &= P(A > b | B = b)f_B(b) \\\\
            &= P(A > b)f_B(b) \text{ because of independence of } A, B \\\\
            &= \int_{min}^{max} \left(\int_{b}^{max} f_A(a) da\right) f_B(b)db \\\\
            &= \int_{min}^{max} \left(1 - \int_{min}^{b} f_A(a) da\right) f_B(b)db \\\\
            &= \int_{min}^{max} \left(1 - F_A(b)\right) f_B(b)db \\\\
            &= \int_{min}^{max} f_B(b)db - \int_{min}^{max} F_A(b)f_B(b)db \\\\
            &= 1 - \int_{min}^{max} F_A(b)f_B(b)db.
\end{align}
However, from this step, I'm not entirely sure if/how to represent $P(A>B)$ by their quantile functions. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: What is the benefit or motivation of expressing a clear relation $P(A > B) = 1 - \int_{y_1}^{y_2} F_A(b)f_B(b)db$ in terms of quantile functions (whose values are in general outside $[0, 1]$)?

Comment: Use the Probability Integral Transform. For instance, $\iint_{F_A^{-1}(u)\gt F_B^{-1}(v)}\mathrm du\mathrm dv$ will do it.  Would that be what you mean by "represent"?  If not, what kind of formula are you hoping for?

Comment: I believe $\int F_A(b) f_B(b) db = \int F_A(b) dF_B(b)$.